# tableView Scroll then progressView corner radius change automatically

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, progress-bar, scrollview

i add progress view in table view .i scroll the uitableView then track corner radius does not show how can i set his corner radius.
even i added the layer corner radius also

```
 progressBar.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 8
 progressBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below swift 5.0 extension to set the corner radius

```
extension UIView{
    func setCorner(withRadius:Int, borderWidth:Int = 0, color: UIColor = .clear){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.borderColor = color
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
progressBar.setCorner(withRadius: 8)//what ever radius you want to set.
```